# Cannot read property 'value' of undefined in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am a beginner in Angular.

html form :

```
    <mat-form-field class = "tp-full-width" style="padding-left: 20px;">
      <input #equiId formControlName="equiId" matInput placeholder = "Equipment Code" value = "">
    </mat-form-field>
```

and button with code :

```
<mat-card-actions >
          <button mat-raised-button color="accent" type="button" style="width:200px;" 
          (click)="add_equi(equiId.value)">control value</button>
</mat-card-actions>
```

and in ts file :

```
this.formGroupContent=new FormGroup({
      equiId:new FormControl()
)}

add_equi(equiId){
    console.log(equiId);
}
```

the problem is that when equiId has a value, console print that value. But when equiId is empty I receive an error :

> Cannot read property 'value' of undefined in angular

I want to receive a message when equiId control is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the E[lvis operator (?)](https://www.joshmorony.com/safely-displaying-data-with-the-elvis-operator/) so that you can avoid the error in console..

```
<button mat-raised-button color="accent" type="button" style="width:200px;" 
          (click)="add_equi(equiId?.value)">control value</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the reactive forms so try to using its properties, like:

```
add_equi() {
    console.log(this.formGroupContent.controls.equiId.value);
  }
```

Remove `#equiId` from your input element and use properties of your form, for more info about reactive forms check out this link : [Reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)